# Can I submit a private domain registration to bing

Tags: domains, bing, private-registration

I have a private domain registration.  Is there any way to submit to Bing without disclosing personal details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by [pinging bing](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4).

Example:

```
http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/sitemap.xml
```